# Google Cloud Run Service Reference Secret within Terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp, google-secret-manager

I am trying to deploy an application in Google Cloud Run with Terraform and there are some secrets I want to reference in the Cloud Run Service. However I am getting this error:

```
Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on main.tf line 122, in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default":
│   122:           value_from {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "value_from" are not expected here.
```

But in the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#value_from) it shows that I can use `value_from` to reference a secret. Is there anyone who knows what is the problem?

**Note:** My `hashicorp/google` provider version is `3.90.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in beta for that provider version:

> value_from - (Optional, Beta) Source for the environment variable's value. Only supports secret_key_ref. Structure is documented below.

So you would either have to use `google-beta` provider [1] or switch to a newer provider version where it is no longer in beta. For example, in the latest provider version [2]:

> value_from - (Optional) Source for the environment variable's value. Only supports secret_key_ref. Structure is documented below.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/3.90.1/docs/guides/provider_versions#using-the-google-beta-provider

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service

Comment: Thank you I have just found out that it was in beta in that version. So the problem solved when I use `google-beta` provider.

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated if correct.